# Embed some user profile fields in a block form

Tags: 7, entities

I've added some fields to user profile.
None of these fields are displayed on registration form, but I want user can edit them quickly when he is logged.
I want to embed some fields in a static content and display them to the user: how can I manage this? Can I create a php page or is it better using hook_form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form within a block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15152/form-within-a-block)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you a start. Probably it is not the most elegant solution, but after 5 minutes of hacking, this is what I got. It works, and updates the profile fields (alone).

```
  function custom_block_info() {
     $blocks['user_profile'] = array(
       'info' => t('User profile edit'),
       'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
     );

     return $blocks;
    }

    function custom_block_view($delta = '') {
      $block = array();

      switch($delta) {
        case 'user_profile':
          $block['subject'] = t('Fill your profile');
          $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('custom_profile_form');
          break;
      }

      return $block;
    }

    function custom_profile_form($form, &$form_state) {
      global $user;

      $form_state['user'] = $user;
      $form['#user'] = $user;
      $form['#user_category'] = 'account';
      $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#weight' => 100,
        '#value' => t('Save'),
      );

      $form['#action'] = url('user/' . $user->uid . '/edit');
      // $form['#validate'][] = 'user_profile_form_validate';
      $form['#submit'][] = 'user_profile_form_submit';
      field_attach_form('user',$user,$form,$form_state);

      return $form;
    }
```

Comment: what category are you talking about? drupal_get_form doesn't take any parameters but form_id. Please notice that I don't want to display the whole form (username, password, mail) I just want the two fields I need.

Comment: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.pages.inc/function/user_profile_form/6  The last parameter category decides which form appears, so basically if u define any profile field u need to define it in a category, visit admin/user/profile and try to add any new profile field and it will ask u for a category, also ur existing profile field must be belonging to some category.

Comment: Sorry, but this issue is related to D7, that doesn't have a profile module anymore. I've seen the category parameter, but I don't know how to add it to a field.

Comment: hey, I have updated the answer to reflect drupal 7. I somehow assumed it to be a drupal 6 question. See if it works for you, it needs to go in a custom module called 'custom'.

Comment: Hope this gives you a start, I couldn't spend much time on this.

Comment: Drupal 7 does have profile.module (It's just hidden) and it certainly does have categories. Just by the way... ;)

Comment: Yeah I know, you gotta unlock it but its not recommended is it? Preferred way is to use fields in the user entity.

Comment: Great man! This did the trick! Thanks! Maybe you know even how to set categories for user fields? I know you can use them, but I couldn't find an UI to set them.

Comment: Thanks for this.
I can see my profile fields now, but i can't save it.. Do you know how? The save button is located above the profile fields, when i click i go to user/uid/edit (like in the code) but there the changes aren't visible. (also not after a refresh).
Do i have to write an update query myself? or how can i make the fields update my profile?
Thanks!

Comment: You should ask this as a new question and reference to this, nobody is going to look at this. You should also provide more details when creating a question.