# Form within a block

Tags: 7, blocks, forms

I'm using `drupal_get_form('event_signup_form')` to embed my custom form inside a block. The form is being rendered as intended, but submitting the form triggers nothing.

The form function itself is called `event_signup_form($form, &$form_state)` and the submit function is called `event_signup_form_submit($form, &$form_state)` but it's not being called.

I am using [hook_block_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) to show the form:

```
function event_block_view($delta = '') {
$blocks = array();
if ($delta ...) {
$blocks['content'] = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('event_signup_form'));
}
}
```

I managed to get this working - here is how (stub):

```
function hook_block_view($delta = '') {
$blocks['content'] = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('event_signup_form'));
}

function event_signup_form() {
// Register form submit handler, same goes for validation handler
$form['#submit'][] = 'event_signup_form_submit';

return $form;
}

function event_signup_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
// This is now triggered
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of Drupal 7, [drupal_get_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) returns a render array instead of a string, so try using:

`drupal_render(drupal_get_form('event_signup_form'));`

to embed the form in the block. For information, see the section [drupal_get_form() returns a render array instead of a string](http://drupal.org/node/224333#unrendered) in the article [Converting 6.x Modules to 7.x](http://drupal.org/node/224333)

Also, I believe your function `event_signup_form($form, &$form_state)` should just be `event_signup_form()` (without arguments).

Comment: But from within hook_block_view($delta = '') http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7 I am returning an array, I'm not printing anything.

Comment: I made a tool that creates block code that you can place in your module: http://browse-tutorials.com/tools/drupal/create-block

Comment: @Kristian ok, does it work with the code you edited into your question?

Comment: Yes I did manage to get it working, I'll add an update to the question

Comment: While this may work (sort of) for the edited question, it is not the *right* way to put a working form within a block. You want a render array, not a string.  You also want to have the arguments (as prescribed by the Form API) for `hook_form()`. See answer by Francisco Luz for correct answer.

Answer (score 12):

My bet is that `$form['#submit'][] = 'event_signup_form_submit';` is the culprit. You set that only if you want an extra submission handler.

This is a working sample code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function MYMODULE_block_info() {
  $blocks = array();

  $blocks['MYBLOCK'] = array(
    'info' => t('My block'), 
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function MYMODULE_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case 'MYBLOCK':
      $block['subject'] = t('My block title');
      $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('MYFORM_form');
    break;
  }
  return $block;
}

/**
 * Custom form.
 */
function MYFORM_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['MYFIELD'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Some Field'),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit Button'),
  );

  return $form;
}

/**
 * Custom form submit function.
 */
function MYFORM_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // You need the have Devel module enabled for dpm() to work.
  dpm($form_state);
}
```

Comment: An excellent example!

Comment: Great example. I didn't need the custom form submit, but the first two functions put my custom form in a block, which is what I was looking for when I found this page. Thanks.

Comment: I think  this should be the accepted answer.