# Call custom form in a block

Tags: 7, forms, blocks

I am trying to call a custom form in a block. The form is written in my custom module.
I tried different ways to call the form, but not getting the form.

Here is the syntax, I last tried.

```
$form = drupal_get_form('my_custom_form');
print drupal_render($form); 
//my_custom_form is my form_id
```

(or)

```
drupal_render(drupal_get_form('my_custom_form'));
```

Here is the link I found a similar question, but didn't get the correct solution for my question. 
[Form within a block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15152/form-within-a-block)

Comment: I tried that way. The below answer is the same for that question. I want a new way of doing it. I want to know an newer methods of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

You should return your form using `drupal_get_form` in the content definition of your block. Drupal will do the rest.

For example like this:

```
function YOURMODULE_block_info()
{
    $blocks = array();

    $blocks['custom_block'] = array(
        'info' => t('Custom block example'),
        'title' => t('Custom block example'),
        'region' => 'content',
        'status' => 1,
    );

    return $blocks;
}

function YOURMODULE_block_view($delta = '')
{
    $block = array();

    switch ($delta) {
        case 'custom_block' :
            $block['content'] = YOURMODULE_block_content();
            break;
    }

    return $block;
}

function YOURMODULE_block_content()
{
    return drupal_get_form('my_custom_form');
}

function my_custom_form($form, &$form_state)
{
    // Build your form

    return $form
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this. Is there any other method to do this?

Comment: You also can directly call the `drupal_render` on the form and return it as `#markup` content for the block ... but you already tried ... which isn't working for you. Do you have some content of the block rendered on the page? (i.e.: the block wrapper html, title, ...)

Comment: Anyway as the requirement is urgent, I am using the old method. Thanks for your help.