# Loading Search Form as a block content

Tags: 7, search

I have several Apache Solr search configurations, filtered to different Content Types to be used on a variety of view pages. These "pages" provide their own search form, but I need to be able to embed these search fields as blocks, so they can be implemented in page layouts within Context.

So, create a block and load the form with drupal_get_form:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info()
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
function example_block_info() {
  $block['mwb_video_block'] = array(
    'info' => t('Example Search Block'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE,
  );

  return $block;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view()
 */
function example_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {
    case "example_search_block":
      $block['subject'] = "";
      $block['content'] = example_render_search_block();
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}

function example_render_search_block() {
  $form = drupal_get_form("search_form");
  return drupal_render($form);
}
```

Simple, right? Well, I tried that with varying results, none returning a form. A DPM of the loaded form object loads in the form, but nothing renders in the return output. Is there a process that i'm missing out on here that only seems to be tied to the Apache Solr search form?

Comment: I think you should use $block['content'] = drupal_get_form("machine_name_form");

Comment: Here is one possible answer: 

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15152/form-within-a-block