# Drupal 7 Display legal module fieldset on user/% instead of user/%/edit

Tags: users

How can I display the legal module fieldset on /user/% instead of /user/%/edit? Please note my /user/% is a view page so I can use views template schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just took a look inside the code of [Legal](http://drupal.org/project/legal) module, what you describe is not possible by design, as of legal is hooking in existing forms:

legale.module line 223

```
function legal_form_user_profile_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
```

legale.module line 223

```
function legal_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
```

You might want to try out building a custom user-page form and hide the unwanted elements from profile form.

For reference in how to to that see this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/3014/13366).

I also think you will need to go a bit further than views only and use [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) to add multiple views on one page.

Comment: I am going further in this asking the option to display the legal fieldset on user/% as an option with a feature request to the Legal module developer. Thanks.