# Embed user edit form in a block

Tags: 7, users, forms, blocks

I am trying to embed current user edit form in block. Actually I want just to embed some of the newly added fields. I tried to follow this code:

[Embed some user profile fields in a block form](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/embed-some-user-profile-fields-in-a-block-form)

But I failed to find the "category", and code does not produce any output except of "save" button.

EDIT: Provided possible solution does not work for me. It does not print custom fields by any means.

Comment: Try with `global  $user; $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('user_profile_form', $user);
      module_load_include('inc', 'user', 'user.pages');` instead of the code mentioned in `custom_block_view` in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for response. I tried replacing the $block['content'] from the example as you suggested but still no form got rendered. Only title "Fill your profile" and nothing else.

Comment: It actually got rendered!! Thanks a lot! I just had to clean the cache. But it refused to render custom fields. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Form within a block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15152/form-within-a-block)